# Can I add variables to a 2D knapsack problem that can take multiple values?

Tags: knapsack-problem, or-tools, cp-sat

this is my first question on stack overflow and I am quite new to OR, so bear with me.

I am trying to solve what could be considered a rectangular 2D knapsack problem with a twist. In order to solve the problem, I need to fill out the entire knapsack. I am, however, allowed to produce rectangles with a minimum height and width - and ratio between these. I would like to build a model that takes this into consideration (and obviously weighs the produced rectangles lower than the ones in existence).

I am currently using the ORTools' CP-SAT model in python. I am open to model changes, if other models better fit this problem. The model solves the ordinary packing problem and finds feasible and optimal solutions, however, the holes left in my knapsack are problematic.

Basically, the dumbest way to solve this would be to create tonnes of rectangles that have different sizes and including them in my variable list with a lower value than the rest. Isn't there a smarter way to go about this?

[This is my solution so far. Don't mind the blue lines, they are part of the problem that I have fixed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBwNi.jpg)
In the image, the hole containing two red rectangles would be suitable for me to produce these two rectangles, however, the crossed out holes are too small (and slim in some places)...

I would appreciate your help. If anything is unclear, please ask!

Comment: Maybe this [sample](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/7188121fb67b645c1faf69e21b93d3fc82c4bc2f/examples/python/knapsack_2d_sat.py) could be of some help!.

Comment: Hey @watchdogs132, thanks for your reply - so quick! I think that "NewOptionalFixedSizeIntervalVar" could be of use in this scenario - if I understand the definition correctly. I will implement it and close the question if it works. Thank you for your quick help :)

Comment: Why don't you add a constraint that says `sum(rectangle_areas) == total_area` ?

Comment: Hey all, sorry for the late response.. This is a spacetime project outside my job and school, so other things sometimes take priority. I tried the NewOptionalFixedSizeIntervalVar and could not really find any use for it. As for your comment @LaurentPerron; right now weight the area filled out by the squares in the maximise function. But I have not thought of the perhaps obvious constraint you describe haha!

Comment: So @LaurentPerron, it works but not quite as intended. The solution can be feasible even if the rectangles don't fill the entire knapsack. This constraint will make the model a lot slower. 

 Is there any way in OR-TOOLS to know the variable values considered inside the model? Fx. what integer an IntVar is at any given moment. Knowing this, I would be able to construct the holes and add a constraint that says, that holes cannot be smaller than x, y. That would be the superior solution to this problem I think.

Of course I meant spare time above -> autocorrect. Thanks for all the help!